# SQL Server Date Query, year and month as separate columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table where year and month are stored in separate columns as integers. The question I have is how to retrieve the previous 12 months from the current date (i.e. the date when the query is run). So, if the date is 15th February 2013, then I want to get records from 15th February 2013 to 14th February 2012 only, and not return any other years and months.

Is there simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Your example uses the DAY but you aren't using a DAY column...

Comment: If you only have year and month, where is day coming from?

Comment: Looking at your example, would you want to retrieve records from February 2012 until today ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to find the date for 1 year ago:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) >= 
      CONCAT(CAST(year AS varchar), CAST(month AS varchar), CAST(date AS varchar))
```

Comment: I have edited your answer since the function is `DATEADD` and not `DATE_ADD`.

Comment: you are correct that it's DATEADD without underscore, but `year` is perfectly acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea, maybe something like this could help :

```
select CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT ( year, month, date ))
from your_table
```

Comment: Assuming he has a `DAY` column, which I understand is confusing looking at his example.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to change the design of that database.
As Edgar Frank Codd sayd, a date is atomic, this is, it can't (or shouldnt) be separated in smaller parts.
If it's not too late, change your design, put the date in datetime format and this will get rid of any kind of problem retrieving dates. You have hundreds of date and time functions to retrieve dates easily, otherwise you will go bald thinking querys.

Select (whatever)
From (table)
where (table's date column) between current_date() AND Dateadd(yy,-1,current_date());

This will be the code for your query if you change your design.
Otherwise, you can do somthing like this:

Select (whatever)
From (table)
where (table.year between (Select MAX(table.year) From table) AND (Select MAX(table.year)-1 From table)) AND table.month = (Try and get the actual month) AND table.day = (Try and get actual day);

As you can see, it's really hard to figure out on what day and month the query is executed.
With the year I assume the maximum year is the actual one...
This is not the way to do things, I highly recommend you to change the design.
Hope it helps.